# Arreglo dentro de otro JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript así que no sé muy bien si lo que quiero es posible
tengo 2 arreglos como el siguiente:

```
let arr1 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5]
];
let arr2 = [1,2,3];
```

quiero comprobar en la consola si el arreglo
`arr2 = [1, 2, 3]` se encuentra en el arreglo `arr1`

he probado usar indexOf `console.log(arr2.indexOf(arr1));`
pero en la consola me sale `-1`.

No tendria que salir `0`? ya que en el `arr1` sí se encuentra lo mismo que en el `arr2`

Espero que me este expresando bien con mi duda

Comment: Importa el orden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La opción rapida seria utilizar la funcion includes, pero esta fallaría debido a que se están comparando dos instancias de objetos diferentes, ejemplo:

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [1,2,3];
```

si evaluamos `arr1 == arr2` nos dará falso, pese a tener el mismo valor, son instancias de objetos diferentes. Si se compara objetos anidados como es el caso que se plantea **Brian M** también fallará.

Lo que nos lleva a comparar de alguna forma los valores mas no los objetos.
De las muchas formas a continuación se describe una de ellas.

```js
let arr1 = [
    [1,2,3],
    [3,4,5]
];
let arr2 = [1,2,3];

const condicion = (elemento) => (elemento).toString() == (arr2).toString();

console.log('utilizando funcion includes')
if(arr1.includes(arr2)){
  console.log('arr1 contiene a arr2')
}else{
  console.log('arr1 no contiene a arr2')
}

console.log('utilizando funcion some ')
if(arr1.some(condicion)){
  console.log('arr1 contiene a arr2')
}else{
  console.log('arr1 no contiene a arr2')
}
```

Cabe mencionar, al convertir ambos arreglos en cadena, el orden de sus elementos deben coincidir.
Si está seguro de que lo que comparará son array y no le importa el orden de los elementos, puede ordenarlos antes de convertirlos en cadena, ejemplo:

```js
let arr1 = [
    [1,2,3],
    [3,4,5]
];
let arr2 = [1,3,2];

const condicion = (elemento) => (elemento).sort().toString() == (arr2).sort().toString();

console.log('utilizando funcion some ')
if(arr1.some(condicion)){
  console.log('arr1 contiene a arr2')
}else{
  console.log('arr1 no contiene a arr2')
}
```

Comment: Si el orden de los elementos debe coincidir, podría caer en que no sean el mismo elemento u objeto. `[1,2,3]` no es igual a `[3,2,1]`

Comment: @Excorpion eso ya lo comenté en la respuesta, leela hasta el final.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Usar [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), y convertirlo a cadena JSON,
para luego comprar ambos usando [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

`indexOf` retornará el valor -1 si no ha encontrado dicho valor.

```js
let arr1 = [[1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 5]];
let arr2 = [1,2,3];

a = JSON.stringify(arr1);
b = JSON.stringify(arr2);

let c = a.indexOf(b);
if(c != -1){
    console.log('elemento presente');
}else{
    console.log('elemento NO presente');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Con `.some` y `.every` se puede hacer, sería si hay alguno que cumpla que todos son iguales en la misma posición:

```js
let arr1 = [[1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 5]];
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

const res = arr1.some(e=> e.length === arr2.length && e.every((a,i)=>a===arr2[i]));

console.log(res)
```

Si no es necesario que esté en la misma posición se puede usar `.includes`: `arr2.includes(a)`

Comment: En este caso, si `arr2` fuera `[1, 2, 3, 4]` también daría `true`

Comment: Tal y como dice Fran, incluso `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` aparece como `true`

Comment: Es verdad, ahi lo arreglé